# Language switcher - Flags in option XSLT IdoSell

Tags: javascript, select, xslt, drop-down-menu

I would like to modify the current xslt code so that a flag is also displayed next to the language name. Currently, the language is displayed in option and as far as I know, it is not possible to insert a flag there. The flags are located under this path "/gfx/standards/[id].svg')", e.g. '/gfx/standards/pol.svg', '/gfx/standards/eng.svg'. Is there a good person here who will help me with this?

Below is the entire code and script.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<iai:component>
    <iai:componentsdata>
        <cdata-start/>
        <div id="freeShipping" class="col-12">
            <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between; align-items: center;">
                <!-- Social Icons -->
                <div id="social-icons-left">
                    <ul class="social-icons">
                        <iaixsl:for-each select="/shop/contact/contact_nodes/node[@type='text' and @title='Facebook']">
                        <a href="{@value}" title="{@title}" class="footer_contact__item footer_contact__item--facebook d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                            <i class="icon-facebook"></i>
                        </a>
                    </iaixsl:for-each>
                    <iaixsl:for-each select="/shop/contact/contact_nodes/node[@type='text' and @title='Instagram']">
                        <a href="{@value}" title="{@title}" class="footer_contact__item footer_contact__item--instagram d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                            <i class="icon-instagram"></i>
                        </a>
                    </iaixsl:for-each>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Settings for language and currency selection -->
                <div class="menu_settings_right">
                  <form id="languageCurrencyForm" action="/settings.php" method="POST">
                    <!-- Language Selection -->
<select name="lang" id="languageSelect" class="menu_settings_language_select">
    <iaixsl:for-each select="/shop/language/option">
        <option>
            <iaixsl:attribute name="value"><iaixsl:value-of select="@id"/></iaixsl:attribute>
            <iaixsl:if test="@selected='true'">
                <iaixsl:attribute name="selected">selected</iaixsl:attribute>
            </iaixsl:if>
            <iaixsl:choose>
                <iaixsl:when test="@id='pol'"><iai:variable vid="Polski"/></iaixsl:when>
                <iaixsl:when test="@id='eng'"><iai:variable vid="English"/></iaixsl:when>
                <iaixsl:when test="@id='ger'"><iai:variable vid="German"/></iaixsl:when>
                <iaixsl:when test="@id='fre'"><iai:variable vid="French"/></iaixsl:when>
                <iaixsl:when test="@id='spa'"><iai:variable vid="Spanish"/></iaixsl:when>
                <iaixsl:when test="@id='cze'"><iai:variable vid="Czech"/></iaixsl:when>
                <iaixsl:when test="@id='lit'"><iai:variable vid="Lithuanian"/></iaixsl:when>
                <iaixsl:when test="@id='slo'"><iai:variable vid="Slovak"/></iaixsl:when>
                <iaixsl:when test="@id='por'"><iai:variable vid="Portuguese"/></iaixsl:when>
                <iaixsl:when test="@id='rum'"><iai:variable vid="Romanian"/></iaixsl:when>
                <iaixsl:when test="@id='ita'"><iai:variable vid="Italian"/></iaixsl:when>
                <iaixsl:when test="@id='rus'"><iai:variable vid="Russian"/></iaixsl:when>
                <iaixsl:when test="@id='ukr'"><iai:variable vid="Ukrainian"/></iaixsl:when>
                <!-- Dodaj więcej warunków dla innych języków -->
                <iaixsl:otherwise><iaixsl:value-of select="@name"/></iaixsl:otherwise>
            </iaixsl:choose>
        </option>
    </iaixsl:for-each>
</select>

                    <!-- Currency Selection -->
                    <select name="curr" id="currencySelect" class="menu_settings_currency_select">
                      <iaixsl:for-each select="/shop/currency/option">
                        <option>
                          <iaixsl:attribute name="value"><iaixsl:value-of select="@id"/></iaixsl:attribute>
                          <iaixsl:if test="@selected='true'">
                            <iaixsl:attribute name="selected">selected</iaixsl:attribute>
                          </iaixsl:if>
                          <iaixsl:value-of select="@id"/> <iaixsl:text> </iaixsl:text><iaixsl:value-of select="@symbol"/>
                        </option>
                    </iaixsl:for-each>
                    </select>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        <cdata-end/>
    </iai:componentsdata>
</iai:component>
```

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var languageSelect = document.getElementById('languageSelect');
    var currencySelect = document.getElementById('currencySelect');

    languageSelect.addEventListener('change', function () {
        document.getElementById('languageCurrencyForm').submit();
    });

    currencySelect.addEventListener('change', function () {
        document.getElementById('languageCurrencyForm').submit();
    });
});
```

I tried to create a custom switcher, but I couldn't connect it to xslt. Languages are loaded automatically depending on what they are available in the store. ChatGPT failed.

Comment: Why is this tagged as `xslt`?